# how to do logging in one file from 2 script which are executing simultaneously?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, logging, optimization

I am new in python. I have one script with many functions. so it was taking about 10 seconds to finish. To improve speed, I have divided one script into two (so now I have two scripts with independent functions) independent scripts. I am importing one script from another. so it can work simultaneously. but in doing so the behaviour of the logger is completely changed. it supposes to be creating and writing in the new log file (every time I run the script). but now it is writing also in previous log files.

so my guess is that my logger configurations are not working in both scripts simultaneously. because of that threading is also running slow.
can anyone please check out my code and help me to find mistakes in it??

```
script_1.py
script_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(sys.argv[0]))        
dat = str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S'))
logger = logging.getLogger("main_script")
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
fh = logging.FileHandler(script_path + '\\..\\main_script_' + dat".log") 
logger_file_path = script_path + '\\..\\main_script_' + dat + ".log"
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
fh.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(fh)

def CloseLogger():
    """CloseLogger function closes the logger """    
    handler = logger.handlers[:]   
    for i in handler:
        i.flush()
        i.close()
        logger.removeHandler(i)

#other independent functions
if__name__== "__main__":
    main_1()

script_2.py
from threading import Thread
from script_1 import *
run_script1 = Thread(target = main_1)
run_script1.start()
logger = logging.getLogger('main_script.script_2') # second part of original script



#other independent functions

if__name__== "__main__":
    run_script2 = Thread(target = main_2)
    run_script2.start()
    run_script2.join()
    run_script2.join()
```

I think either I am doing mistakes in threading or in logger configuration.
please help me to find my mistakes.
if you need more information please let me know.
thank you

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLVNF.png)

Comment: For clarification, you say it's writing in the previous file instead of a new one. Based on your variable `dat`, would that mean it is getting the previous time, and not the current time?

Comment: nop, I do not think so, because it was working perfectly on my old script when I had all the functions in one script.

Comment: what do you think am I importing script_1 perfectly? because we can import module or script in two way. 1) import module name 2) from module import *

Comment: You imported correctly. Print out `dat` each time you open the file, then run your script a few different times. Is the value of `dat` different? If it is, print the name of the log file. Does it match to the value of `dat`?

Comment: Also I notice `fh = logging.FileHandler(script_path + '\\..\\main_script_' + dat".log")`. Is this a typo in SO or in your actual script? Should be `... dat + ".log"`. Perhaps your script has an error in it, and you're running a previous version

Comment: @Treyten Carey, I have tried as you asked. yes, dat and log file name are the same. but I think it kept open all the previous log files. so every time I run the script it starts writing in previous files and also new files. but if I restart my spyder and run the script again then it will start writing new log files. for debug now, i am running only one script_1.

Comment: I do not know how to upload a picture in comments so I have uploaded it my question. you can see the picture files names are different but those files are modified at the same time. after 3 times running the script, i have restarted the spyder.

Comment: " '\\..\\main_script_'  " because I have to create my log file outside of the project folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found out the reason. I have to close the logger properly. so my code for closing a logger is...

```
handlers = logger.handlers[:] #close logger
for handler in handlers:
    handler.flush()
    handler.close()
    logger.removeHandler(handler) # was not removing handler
logging.shutdown()
```

Please correct me if I am wrong.
Thank you @Treyten Carey